# What are the downsides of saving data models in keychain?

Tags: ios, swift, security, keychain

I understand Keychain is designed for saving Passwords, InternetPasswords, cryptographic keys, etc. However, why not just save small encodable models as well?

For example, an encodable and decodable structure that holds about 100 properties of user sensitive preferences.

I tried this and it worked pretty well. Although, there is not much concrete information available and I want to understand if there are any downsides to doing this.

Comment: @PaFi : Have you experienced this? or is it speculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing actually prevents you from doing it, as the encoded data model will be in the form of Data/NSData. There may be a pair of points to keep in mind before going in that direction:

- there’s an actual size limit per
  single keychain item ( which I personally could not find officially stated, but I remember that writing a keychain item which data size was greater than about 2 MB, led to a keychain write error ). That means you should be careful on how big the data model is ( for example using short CodingKeys instead of the actual property names, would use less bytes in the resulting data block to be written )
- keychain data does not get deleted when the user deletes the app. Whether this will stay like this forever or not I can’t tell, but is a fact as per now, and this means you may need to put a logic in your app to make sure that another installation on top of the previous one may not use the old/dirty data as unnecessary

I don’t discourage you from using the keychain for that, but in case, there are alternative approaches, like storing an encryption key on the keychain and using it to encrypt/decrypt your actual data models and write them securely in your app document folder. You can combine this with extra steps like NSFileProtectionComplete setting, make the encryption key in the keychain accessible only if the device is actually protected by passcode, and maybe, if you plan to store quite a lot of data, combine encryption and CoreData together.

Hope it helps

Comment: laco: Thank you for your detailed answer. You have covered everything that was on my mind and more. I want to wait to hear a few more experiences before I accept your answer.